# How to turn off element CSS background when dragged

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop, cursor

I've build a drag and drop interface using JavaScript where users can click and drag a link (that sometimes has a CSS background image) and drop it onto the canvas.

My problem is that the mouse cursor has the link background image beneath it during dragging. I need to add my own cursor design, so is there any way to turn this CSS background off so that it doesn't follow the mouse upon dragging?

Comment: have you tried something like setting the background to `none` just before dragging and then setting it back after?

Comment: If joseph's solution doesn't work you could try doing the same trick, but onmousedown and onmouseup.

Comment: Will give it a try, but probably deactivate the bg on drag because otherwise the links :hover event will be cancelled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found for this problem was to use jQuery to assign e.preventDefault() to the click event of the link, thus disabling the background drag effect. Then, if you want a custom cursor upon dragging, write a script to match an absolutely positioned div's (with the image as the background) x,y cords to the mouse position.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting :active pseudo class for anchor tags?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

then if that isn't work quite yet you could use !important after your deceleration possibly?

and example could be

```
.links:active {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

when the user releases the background image should return.